# Как с помощью Retrofit2 обработать null JsonObject?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, null

Функция запроса:

```
fun requestBody(call: Call<Data>, OnRequestCallback: OnRequestCallback) {
        call.clone().enqueue(object : Callback<Data> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Data>, t: Throwable) {
                myLog("onFailure", t.message.toString())
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Data>, response: Response<Data>) {
                when (response.isSuccessful) {
                    true -> {}
                    false -> {}
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Data class:

```
data class Data(

    @SerializedName("code")
    val code:String,

    @SerializedName("message")
    val message:String,

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Nullable
    val data:JsonObject?
)
```

Ответ c сервера:

```
{
    "code": "1",
    "message": "Вход выполнен успешно",
    "data": null
}
```

Но во время выполнения запроса :

```
Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonNull
```

Вроде в `data class` указываю что `"data"` может быть и нулевым (`null`), но не выходит.
Как правильным образом это реализовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В библиотеке Gson `JsonNull` является наследником `JsonElement`, но не `JsonObject`.
Поэтому не может быть приведён. В самом формате `json` нет типов - они определяются по содержимому и поэтому конкретный тип `null`-поля не может быть определён.
Либо сделайте дата-класс для этого поля и укажите его тип, либо задайте тип `JsonElement`:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Nullable
val data:JsonElement?
```

Comment: понятно, спасибо)